# Django Post Model with Images in specific location

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working with a very simple blog-post-style model right now

```
class TripReport(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=False, related_name='trip_countries')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm looking to add photos to the model. I know I can use the Django models.ImageField, but I want there to possibly be multiple photos and at specific locations throughout the content TextField. It seems like I would have to use a separate model to upload the photos, then use a ManyToMany relationship to tie them to the Trip Report model, but I'm not sure how I could make sure the TextField injects them at the right spot.

Comment: Create predefined set of directories and map them to the fields. So when users send you images, they supply what that image is, like `{'image_type': 'hotel', 'image': <content>}` and handle that data accordingly.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without predefined set of directories?

Comment: I believe this is the best way i know, since you want to tackle with many images. And if your images are big, you are forced to send them as `multipart-form-data`, many restrictions to upload images via rest api. I suggest you to search for multiple images rest api.

Comment: if I upload them to s3, does this bypass that problem? can my api just give me back the url?

Comment: Actually i'm not quite sure, but i think i've heard that you can upload images to s3 directly from client and send links to the server.